# how to use a separate url rules file for a rewrite map

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

i am using microsoft url rewrite module not urlrewriter.net.

is there a way to keep the rules for the rewrite map in a separate file and not in the web.config file

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use a Custom Rewrite Provider.  [You can download the samples and source code here.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=rewriteextensibility&DownloadId=9257)

The samples has support for using a database or a flat text file.  I find the database option more friendly since you can easily build an ASP.NET web interface on top of this.

For more info, [read this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/803/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module/).